# Database migration issue with Dictionary type property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a model called `Testimonials` which contains various properties of data types `int`,`string`, and `DateTime`. I have modified my model to contain another property of type `Dictionary<string,Boolean>`. I have been trying to migrate the database to accommodate this but the system does not seem to detect this new property. `Testimonials` is the only model within the context (and contains only test data) and so I have deleted the database and `.mdf` for a clean rebuilding of the database. I also deleted old "Migrations" folders from the project. I have also recompiled the entire project many times since the modification of `Testimonials` model.

I perform the following in the Package Manager Console:

`enable-migration -ContextTypeName myProjectName.Models.myProjectNameContext`

`add-migration InitialCreate`

After this step the `xxxxxxxxxxx_InitialCreate.cs` migration file is created and viewing it I see that there is no database code for the `Dictionary<string,Boolean>` property which was added to my Model, only generation for the properties I had before. Entering the command: `update-database` into the Package Manager Console generates the incorrect database as expected, seemingly identical to the structure of the previous database.

I have also tried re-creating the `TestimonialsController.cs` which had no effect.

Is there something incompatible about the property type `Dictionary<string, Boolean>` or am I just doing something fundamentally wrong/dumb?

I would also note that I am very new to MVC 5, entity-framework, and code first migration.

Edit:

I have applied the changes below such that the `Dictionary` is its own Model.

My `Testimonials.cs`:

```
public class Testimonial
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Testimonial")]
    [StringLength(600, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be less than 600 characters.", MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Vote> VoteList { get; set; } 

}
```

My `Vote.cs` (what was the dictionary):

```
public class Vote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Testimonial VotedOn { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public bool UpDown { get; set; } //True is upvote, False is downvote.
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

The subsequent `xxxxxxxxx_InitialCreate.cs`:

```
public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Testimonials",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Content = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 600),
                        CreationTime = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        Author = c.String(),
                        Rating = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
            
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Votes",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        User = c.String(),
                        UpDown = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        DateTime = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        VotedOn_Id = c.Int(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Testimonials", t => t.VotedOn_Id)
                .Index(t => t.VotedOn_Id);
            
        }
        
        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Votes", "VotedOn_Id", "dbo.Testimonials");
            DropIndex("dbo.Votes", new[] { "VotedOn_Id" });
            DropTable("dbo.Votes");
            DropTable("dbo.Testimonials");
        }
```

As you can see the `Vote` properly references the `Testimonial` however the `IEnumerable<Vote>` is never generated. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: What do you mean IEnumberable<Vote> is never generated? I can see Votes table in migration code as well as Testimonials foreign key in it.

Comment: My understanding of MySql is poor. I realize now that the entity framework will generate that list from the foreign keys. Thank you for your help. I have it all working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF you cant use Dictionary to map POCO properties to database tables, but you can use normal one-to-many mapping, something like this:

```
public class KeyValue {
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public Testimonial Testimonial { get; set; }
}

public class Testimonial{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<KeyValue> Dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

BTW, your issue is not related with MVC, but EF and Code-First mappings.

Comment: I have modified my Model to reflect the changes above but it still does not get generated within the database. See edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that can accomoddate the Dictionary that you want to use.

```
   Public class DictionaryModel { 
    public int DictionayID; 
    public string StringVar; 
    public bool BooleanVar;
  }
```

Then you reference the DictionaryModel as a list on your Testimonials model:

```
public class Testimonials{
   ...
   public List<DictionayModel> Dictionary; 
}
```

As an example I set the Name "DictionaryModel", but you can define with the name that makes more sense to your code.

Comment: I have modified my Model to reflect something similar to your suggestion (closer to E-Bat's response). However I am still having essentially the same issue. See the edit above.

Comment: Just saw that you figured out how to solve problem. The key to understand Code First is learn how models are converted to the database. Good Job!